# How can I sore results by highest of two dates?

Tags: mysql, left-join, sql-order-by

I have two tables:
1. questions table that includes: question_id, date, more data
2. connection table: connection_id, question_id, connection_date, more data

I have the following joined table
question_id, question_date, connection_id, connection_date left joined on question_id.
So I have some rows with connection date and some with NULL (when there is no matching connection)

Following is a data sample:

```
question_id | question_date | connection_id | connection_date
500         | 28-10-2018    |  7            |  22-12-2018
501         | 29-10-2018    |  NULL         |  NULL
505         | 01-11-2018    |  8            |  10-12-2018
506         | 05-11-2018    |  9            |  02-12-2018 
507         | 07-12-2018    |  NULL         |  NULL
```

I need the results table to be sorted by bigger of the two values connection_date & question_date so the result will be:

```
question_id | question_date | connection_id | connection_date
500         | 28-10-2018    |  7            |  22-12-2018
505         | 01-11-2018    |  8            |  10-12-2018
507         | 07-12-2018    |  NULL         |  NULL
506         | 05-11-2018    |  9            |  02-12-2018 
501         | 29-10-2018    |  NULL         |  NULL
```

How can I achieve that by using mysql alone ?

Comment: Step 1: store dates using a date data type

Comment: they are of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort using `GREATEST`:

```
SELECT question_id, question_date, connection_id, connection_date
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY GREATEST(question_date, COALESCE(connection_date, question_date)) DESC;
```

For an explanation of why `COALESCE` is being used, in case the `connection_date` be `NULL`, we disregard it and only use the `question_date`.  This answer assumes that the `question_date` would be never be `NULL`.

Based on the @strawberry comment, if you are storing your dates as text, then we would have to make an extra call to `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT question_id, question_date, connection_id, connection_date
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    GREATEST(STR_TO_DATE(question_date, '%d-%m-%Y'),
             COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(connection_date, '%d-%m-%Y'),
                      STR_TO_DATE(question_date, '%d-%m-%Y'))) DESC;
```

Please avoid storing your dates as text, and instead use a proper date column.